# Can we use objects inherited from WinForms Control as keys of a .NET Hashtable?

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, hashtable

We use a component implemented in a DLL. It is inherited from System.Windows.Forms.Control. We need to use it as keys in a .NET Hashtable object.

As [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx),

> The objects used as keys by a Hashtable are required to override the Object.GetHashCode method (or the IHashCodeProvider interface) and the Object.Equals method (or the IComparer interface).

But the control we are talking about does not have its own implementation of the GetHashCode method. The [documentation for Object.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) tells us that

> If GetHashCode is not overridden, hash codes for reference types are computed by calling the Object.GetHashCode method of the base class, which computes a hash code based on an object's reference

Does it mean we can safely use the control "as is" in hashtables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only ever care for object identity when you do this.  In other words, you would *never* want two controls to map to the same hash table slot.  Never accurate to +/- 1%

The default Object.GetHashCode() and Object.Equals() implementations that the Control class inherits are already perfect, they implement object reference identity.

And of course you should `Dictionary<Control, Something>`, Hashtable was 8 years ago.

Comment: Yes, strongly typed Dictionary - though it is based on a hashtable. As for `Object.GetHashCode`, I would be glad to look at its implementation using any .NET reflector tool to be sure 100% - but unfortunately it is unmanaged implementation...  By the way, even Microsoft still uses Hashtable instead of Dictionary in samples for Extender Providers [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229066%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but what is good for us in the context of my question, they use Controls as keys in Hashtables.

Comment: You cannot go by example code that was written when .NET 1.0 was released.