# non generic HashCode.Combine

Tags: c#

I am a bit confused about calling `HashCode.Combine` in a non generic way

`HashCode` has `public void Add<T> (T value);`

but not `public void Add (object value);`

In my case I need to calculate the combined hashcode of an unknown number of objects of unknown types.
Is it OK to do:

```
object v1 = ...
object v2 = ...
object v3 = ...

var hashCodeStruct = new HashCode();
hashCodeStruct.Add(v1);
hashCodeStruct.Add(v2);
hashCodeStruct.Add(v3);
var hashCode = hashCodeStruct.ToHashCode();
```

?

Comment: Why are the number of objects unknown? How does the type not know how many fields it has?

Comment: Can you talk us through _why_ you are generating a hashcode?

Comment: @njwills - basically reflection code getting the member with certain attributes and calculating their combined hashcode

Comment: What happened when you tried this (did it compile, what hashcode did you get when running)? What are your concerns?

Comment: And did https://stackoverflow.com/a/18066753/34092 work for you?

Comment: Are you worried that calling `Add<object>` will do something different than `Add<SomeOtherType>` even if you pass in the same object?

Comment: yes @sweeper exactly, otherwise if your answer is that it is OK can you just confirm that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Add<object>(x)` and `Add<SomeOtherType>(x)` will produce the same hash code. The only difference is that the former will *box* `x` if `x` is a value type. I'm pretty sure `Add` is made generic so that boxing does not occur if you pass in a value type. However, this is irrelevant here, because you are dealing with reflected `object`s (which are possibly boxed before the call to `Add`).

[Here's](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/HashCode.cs,09a29596cac3406a,references) the reference source of `Add`:

```
public void Add<T>(T value)
{
    Add(value?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
}

...

private void Add(int value)
{

    ...
```

It just very simply calls the private `Add` with `value`'s hash code. It is easy to see that the same implementation of `GetHashCode` will be called no matter what `T` is, as long as `value` is the same object, because runtime polymorphism.